# How to automatically remove private fields and methods in Java classes

Tags: java, private-members, code-cleanup

I have a code generator which generates classes with a lot of private code like:

```
class A {

  private void meth1() { ... }
  private int var1;

  private class SubA { private void meth2() {...} }
}
```

I'm looking for a tool which would remove all unused private fields/methods and inner classes without human intervention. I would also like it to work on source code instead of byte code to be able to conduct metrics on the generated source code. Changing the code generator would be possible but I'm looking for something simpler.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what code generator are you using? Perhaps you need to fiddle with its settings or input.

Comment: My own :-). It's named DiaGen and is part of the DiaSuite tool suite: http://diasuite.inria.fr/.

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) is a fantastic idea that has this feature built in.  It will automatically let you know private methods/members that have not been used within a class.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clear I need something automatic. Indeed, the code is generated and I don't want to manually clean hundreds of classes each time I press the 'generate' button.

Comment: You don't need to do it on a file by file basis. You can do it on a whole project, and even whole working sets.

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to require this step from my users, I would prefer giving them a clean code.

Answer (score 0):

[ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) does a pretty good job with this at the object level. It can give you a report that you can use to track down the unused methods in the source. I don't know of a tool that automatically strips the source of unused methods.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm indeed looking for something automatic on the at source level.